# URL issue: paperclip-av-transcoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video, paperclip

I am trying to implement paperclip-av-transcoder gem. I have checked everything but not able to find what I am doing wrong here. I'm writing steps which I have followed.

Added into gemfile

```
--> gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
```

Added into my model

```
--> has_attached_file :video_file, :styles => {
    :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
  }, :processors => [:transcoder]    
--> validates_attachment_content_type :video_file, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

created schema to add column name

```
"video_file_meta"
```

In my view file

```
video_tag(video.video_file.url, controls: true, autobuffer: true, size: "320x240")
```

I have checked video in public/system folder it is properly saved I am able to see that video there but I am not able to see that in my view file.

```
Video Url -> /system/videos/video_files/000/000/003/original/tingtong_464.mp4?1497851104
```

I am sharing screens to show how it looks in the browser.
[image]

Comment: Try integrating this - http://videojs.com/ . It supports different video formats , that's what is causing the issue for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently working model file code:

```
 has_attached_file :video_file, :styles => {
     :medium => { :geometry => "500x500", :format => 'jpg' },
     :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100", :format => 'jpg' }
  }, :processors => [:transcoder]

validates_attachment_content_type :video_file,
    :content_type => [
      "video/mp4", 
      "video/quicktime",
      "video/3gpp",
      "video/x-ms-wmv",
      "video/mov",
      "video/flv",
      ],
    :message => "Sorry! We do not accept the attached file type"
```

I guess I am not resizing my video file in any other video format so it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything from my point is correct, except Paperclip requires at least one field in database - `*_file_name` (for you it's `video_file_file_name`), but you didn't added it and Paperclip can't construct url properly. Read more https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage

Comment: it is by default created as we are using paper clip.  Check! https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Mh452BQAQWz5_1VWFukmbbDkd_XRc7Kd6oD7YsemjIw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: maybe Firefox on Linux doesn't support mp4? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264 and MP3 is not built directly into Firefox. Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware (the hardware also needs to be able to support the profile used to encode the video, in the case of MP4). Firefox supports these formats on the following platforms: Linux since Firefox 26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs)

Comment: "maybe Firefox on Linux doesn't support mp4?" it is not working for any os I have checked on windows too. I guess I should generate media file which firefox & chrome browser supports.